# Flutter Error: StackOverflowError - BuildContext

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-localizations

I came accross with StackOverFlow error which caused by self reference. I do not know how to fix it?

**TravelBlog.dart**

```
class Travelblog extends StatelessWidget {
final _list = Travel.generateMembersMain(context);

final _pageCtrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.9);

static BuildContext get context => context; *//I know I have to use _context, but i do not know how?*
```

**Travel.dart**

```
static List<Travel> generateMembersMain(BuildContext context) {
return [
Travel(
      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.stPatricksCathedral,
      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.classics,
      'lib/assets/images/screenshot10.png',
      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.stPatricksCathedraltext1,
      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.stPatricksCathedraltext2,
      'https://goo.gl/maps/CTw3a1jrGbyNQRSu8'),
]
}
```

I use context for Applocalization.

Answer (score 0):

In StatelessWidgets, `context` is explicitly available inside the `build` method. So your call to `Travel.generateMembersMain(context)` has to be done inside the `build` method and not at the top declaration of the `TravelBlog` StatelessWidget.

So your code didn't show the `build` method or other parts of the file (it should so that the solution can take other factors into account), but then changing

```dart
class Travelblog extends StatelessWidget {
final _list = Travel.generateMembersMain(context);

final _pageCtrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.9);

static BuildContext get context => context; *//I know I have to use _context, but i do not know how?*
```

to

```dart
class Travelblog extends StatelessWidget {
  final _pageCtrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.9);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _list = Travel.generateMembersMain(context);
    
    // other UI building and return statement
```

should solve the problem.

If you were using a StatefulWidget instead, then you might have needed to do this assignment in `initState` as `context` is also available there.